# Website and DB Backup - Windows Dedicated Servers and SQL Express

Tags: windows, web-server, database, sql

I have inherited a number of dedicated windows web servers running websites and local SQL Express Databases.

We want to backup both the sites and the databases remotely - maybe to some cloud storage space or something similar.

I was thinking of using something like http://sqlbackupandftp.com/ for the DB's - which can FTP to some purchased online storage, then using windows backup to copy the sites, but not sure if windows backup can copy to an online space.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, back up the sites and database to a local folder onto the server using your preferred backup tool. If you have an online backup account like Rackspace or Amazon or idrive, you can install their application (runs as service) on all the servers and you can install Management software on your PC and schedule backups to backup from that local folder to online storage.